# How to make USA first in my drop down menu?

Tags: php

I just simply wanted to know how I could make United States appear as the first option in my drop down menu. I currently have a country drop down menu that's in order by name. If there is a way I can just get USA to appear first and not repeat that would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code for the drop down menu

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from country order by name");
```

PS: I know MySQL is outdated or what ever... This is all just back end stuff.

Comment: MySQL is not outdated.

Comment: @EricJ. i guess he means the mysql_* library of php, and thats seriously outdated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just order everything alphabetically, but set USA as selected on load?

Comment: mysql_* PHP api to access Mysql database is not just outdated. It is **deprecated** and has been removed in PHP version 7. So your code will not run on update to Php7. You'd better turn to mysqli_* or even better start using PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1 (recommended)** Make the US the first result in your result set

```
SELECT * 
FROM country 
ORDER BY case when name = 'USA' then 1 else 2 end, 
name ASC
```

**Option 2**: Don't select it in your query and display it first (hardcode it in)

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from country where name != 'USA' order by name");
```

**Option 3**: Display it first (hardcode it in) and then skip in while iterating through your resultset

```
if ($row['name'] === 'USA') {
   continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **UNION**:

```
SELECT * FROM country WHERE name = 'USA' 
UNION SELECT * FROM country WHERE name != 'USA'
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

```
<select>
  <option value="1">USA</option>
<?php
        $query =  "SELECT * from country where name != 'USA' order by name";
        $result = mysqli_query($bd,$query);
        while ($country = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value='".$country['cod']."'>".$country['name']."</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
```

Option 2

```
<select>
<?php       
$query =  $query =  "SELECT * from country where name != 'USA' order by name";      $result = mysqli_query($bd,$query);         
while ($country = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $country['cod']; ?>" <?php if ($country['name']=='USA') {echo SELECTED;}?>><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>";         
<?php } ?> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY (country_name = 'USA') DESC, country_name ASC

Here country_name as field in country table

Add this above line to your query..Then onLoad USA selected in drop down..